# Raising error or returning None

Tags: python, error-handling

I have a method `poker` defined as below:

```
def poker(hands):
'''Returns the best hand from a list of hands.

    Parameters:
        hands: list

    Example:
        poker(hands) => hands
'''
    return max(hands, key=hand_rank)
```

As mentioned in the docstrings, this function `returns the best hand from a list of hands`. 
The issue I am facing is while passing an empty list of hands to this function. Hypothetically and for greater coverage, I want to add such a test case.

Should I raise an error or should I return `None` object ?

Generally, how do I decide where an error should be raised and where should it not?

Comment: The code, as posted, is incorrectly indented and will not work. Even if corrected, though, this is not a question for Code Review. You are asking not for a critique of the code, but to extrapolate to best practices in general.

Comment: @200_success Sorry about that. I would be happy if you can move this question to a more appropriate StackExchange site.

Answer (score 4):

There is no universal rule and this particular decision is use-case specific. Note that there are other options as well, like returning `-1` for an empty list.

If we consider that `max()` naturally does not work with empty sequences:

```
In [1]: max([])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-8d2766aecf92> in <module>()
----> 1 max([])

ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence
```

Then, throwing an error makes more sense in this particular situation. If you do so, you can empower your docstring with a doctest:

```
def poker(hands):
    """
    Returns the best hand from a list of hands.

        Parameters:
            hands: list

        Example:
            poker(hands) => hands

    Raises a ValueError in case of empty list of hands:

    >>> poker([])
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      ...
    ValueError: Empty list of hands.
    """
    if not hands:
        raise ValueError("Empty list of hands.")

    return max(hands, key=hand_rank)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is easy to decide wether to raise an exception or not. Sometimes not. The reason for that are semantics.

I will try to break it down:

Something strange happens between one element in the list and zero elements in the list of hands. After all the returned element is always an element of the list given. The point at this statement isn't true anymore it's an exception.

You can rephrase your function that it will return the list given sorted by excellence. Implicitly the best hand will be on top of the list. So if you input an empty list the valid output would be and empty list. There is no exception. By doing that you solved one part of the problem (best on top) and externalize the problem (are there any elements) to the caller who certainly will raise an exception.